# fill space between a quadrilateral drawn with four lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, fill

I want to fill the space between four lines (quadrilateral) using gray color using tikz.  How can I do it.

I also want to tag the origin point as 's'

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\mode<handout>{
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{block}{Pareto Optimal Solutions}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\coordinate (Bone) at (1.7,2.8);
\coordinate (Btwo) at (3.2,1.2);
\coordinate (Bthree) at (4,2.8);
\draw [thick,-] (Origin) -- (Bone) (Bone) -- (Bthree) (Bthree) -- (Btwo) (Btwo) -- (Origin) node {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that tikz comes with a rather extensive manual?

Comment: @JohnKormylo You are right, but a novice would maybe use rather *too* instead of *rather*.

Comment: @gernot - The trick is use a pdf viewer with search features and start at the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label={[below]$s$}] (Origin)   at (0,0);
\coordinate (Bone) at (1.7,2.8);
\coordinate (Btwo) at (3.2,1.2);
\coordinate (Bthree) at (4,2.8);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\draw [thick,-,fill=gray] (Origin) -- (Bone) -- (Bthree) -- (Btwo) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** To add the label *S* in the middle, you can either guess the coordinates, using e.g. something like

```
\node at (2.5,2) {$S$};
```

or you can compute the position:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
...
\node at ($0.25*(Origin)+0.25*(Bone)+0.25*(Btwo)+0.25*(Bthree)$) {$S$};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if, I want to add the tag "S" inside the filled area in the middle ?

Comment: @Shew See the edit of my post.